# Parallelization: package "parallel" instead of "mclapply"

Tags: r, parallel-processing, mclapply

I am trying to convert this code to the one that can be executed on Windows:

```
numCores <- detectCores()
results <- mclapply(seq(1, 500), function(file, fID){
  myData <- fread(file.path(dirPath, fID, paste0(file, ".csv")))
  return(cbind(myData, rep(file, nrow(myData))))
}, mc.cores = numCores, fID = 1)
```

Based on using [this tutorial](http://blog.dominodatalab.com/simple-parallelization/), I wrote the following code...

**UPDATE: The correct code is provided below:**

```
getAllMyData <- function(numCores,folderID)
{
  dirPath = paste0("D:/home/", folderID, '/')
  cl <- makeCluster( 4 )
  allTrips = parLapply(cl, 1:200, function(z){
    myData <- read.csv(paste0(dirPath, z, ".csv"))
    return(cbind(myData , rep(z, nrow(myData))))
  })
  stopCluster(cl)  
  return(allTrips)
}

numCores <- detectCores()
allMyData <- getAllMyData(numCores,1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first code calls a function

```
function(file, fID)
```

Your second code, by contrast, uses

```
function(dirPath,fID)
```

That’s the error.

Comment: Thank you. I updated my post where I posted the correct code. However, it's strange that the runtime is almost the same as the serialized code.

Comment: @KlausosKlausos It's not so surprising: reading data from disk (which is the majority of what your code is doing) cannot be parallelised efficiently because it is an IO bound, not a CPU bound operation.